# Правила пунктуации. Заменяет ли тире союзы?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, поэзия

Песня из кинофильма «Любовь земная» (1974) «Даль великая» (слова Роберта Рождественского) известна многим, особенно старшему поколению. Припев:

*Мой родимый край, место отчее,

**Ты и праздник мой и броня.**

Память общая, и песня общая

У моей земли и у меня*.

Вопрос:
Нужно ли тире во второй строке: *Ты **—** и праздник мой и броня*?

Интернет в большинстве случаев приводит стихотворения поэтов с ошибками, другие сайты эти ошибки подхватывают — и получается во всех местах единый клон одного и того же текста с ошибками. Так что сверять ответ на поставленный вопрос в Сети — сомнительный момент.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что вопрос сформулирован неверно. Здесь не может быть никакого союза.

• Правильный вопрос, считаю, такой: нужно ли тире между подлежащим и сказуемым?
И я бы добавила еще один: нужна ли запятая перед "и броня"?

Почему? Потому что теоретически возможны четыре варианта пунктуации:
а) Ты и праздник мой и броня ([песни из фильмов](http://pesnifilm.ru/load/ljubov_zemnaja/dal_velikaja_quot_ljubov_zemnaja_quot/806-1-0-1755));
б) Ты — и праздник мой и броня ([сборник диктантов](http://shcoole.do.am/publ/diktanty/diktanty_po_russkomu_jazyku_7_klass/punktuacija_pri_obrashhenii/5-1-0-35));
в) Ты — и праздник мой, и броня ([Большое собрание стихотворений...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=IvujAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1293&lpg=PT1293&dq=%D0%A2%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=J83hTQk5ZZ&sig=ACfU3U3he3-_W39vCV2g0igzBdwly82Aqw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvgLeV4ZmDAxWLPhAIHVuXD684ChDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%A2%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false));
г) Ты и праздник мой, и броня ([песни композитора Е. Птичкина](http://blog.norma40.ru/?p=3021)).

**О тире** ([Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91)):

> **8.** Если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое — формой именительного падежа существительного, тире между ними обычно не ставится: ***Он порча, он чума, он язва** здешних мест* (Кр.); ***Я** честный **человек** и никогда не говорю комплиментов* (Ч.).
> Однако тире в этом случае ставится:
> **1)** при логическом подчеркивании: ***Я — страница** твоему перу. Всё приму. Я белая страница. **Я — хранитель** твоему добру…* (Цв.)...

**О запятой** ([Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)):

> **1.** Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимися союзами ***и…и, да…да***... ставится **запятая**...
> **2.** При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом ***и***, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): *Кругом было **и светло и зелено*** (Т.)...

•• Как именно задумывал поэт — сказать трудно.
Но если только по правилам, то верен последний вариант — без тире, но с запятой:
***Ты и праздник мой, и броня.***
Точно такое же написание зафиксировано в [Нотном архиве России](http://www.notarhiv.ru/ruskomp/ptichkin/noti/1%20(20).pdf).

••• Для сравнения:
«Ты моя надежда, ты моя отрада» и «Ты — моя надежда, ты — моя отрада» (название песни, А. Пахмутова — Н. Добронравов).